# Modify and manipulate JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is an array example I have:

```
var array= ['business>management', 'News>Entertainment News', 'business>Entrepreneurship'];
```

I want this result:

```
['business', 'management', 'News', 'Entertainment News', 'Entrepreneurship']
```

It means, separate from this '>'
No duplicate

This is an example of where I'm at but it just removes the arrow '>' [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/7sxz9m03/69/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) combination for example. Read from the docs:

> The `Set` object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.
>
> The `reduce()` method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in single output value.

Please see a possible working solution.

```js
const array = ['business>management', 'News>Entertainment News', 'business>Entrepreneurship'];

const result = array.reduce((a,c) => {
  c.split('>').forEach(e => a.add(e));
  return a;
}, new Set());

const unique = Array.from(result);

console.log(unique);
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: This is Perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

try this one -

```
const array = ['business>management', 'News>Entertainment News', 'business>Entrepreneurship'];
let newArray = []
array.map((item)=>{
    let newData = item.split(">").map((itemIn)=>{ 
      newArray.push(itemIn) 
      return item
      })
    return newData
})
console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Simplified

let array = ['business>management', 'News>Entertainment News', 'business>Entrepreneurship'];

let separated = array.map((item, ii) => {
    return item.split(">")
}).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b)).filter((value, index, self) => {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
});

console.log(separated)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to create an array of strings split by `'>'`. Then you can put these results into a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to remove duplicates, and then back into an array using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`).

```js
const array = ['business>management', 'News>Entertainment News', 'business>Entrepreneurship'];

const result = [...new Set(array.flatMap(str => str.split('>')))];
console.log(result);
```

If you can't use `.flatMap()` due to compatibility concerns, you can always use `.map()` and then flatten the array afterwards using [`.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) which has much better browser comptability:

```js
const arr = ['business>management', 'News>Entertainment News', 'business>Entrepreneurship'];

const result = [...new Set([].concat(...arr.map(s => s.split('>'))))];
console.log(result);
```